# Layer-layer opacity

Tags: html, css

I have two layer, I'd like both to blend, how can I change their transparency to make one see-able from its upper overlapped area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `z-index`, `position`, and `opacity`

**HTML:**

```
<div id="layer1"></div>
<div id="layer2"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#layer1, #layer2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}

#layer1 {
    z-index:0;
    background-color:red;
}

#layer2 {
    z-index:1;
    background-color:blue;
    opacity:0.5;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/QqEdb/

Comment: Thanks a lot, but is there another (IE-free) css way to get this done ?

Comment: @Serious Ragged Hippie: This isn't IE-specific or anything, why would you sacrifice compatibility if it's so easy? Anyways, if you're not targeting IE, use my code :D

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use CSS, and use the `opacity` tag.  It requires a bit of work, because older versions of IE require non-standard settings, but this is an example:

```
.transparentLayer {
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; // IE8
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);                  //  IE7 or older
    opacity: 0.5; // all real browsers
}
```

Change the `0.5` or `50` to be the amount of opacity you want (0=clear, 1/100=solid).

Comment: I'll give OZ the +1 for you since you don't have enough points to actually `+1` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS3 `opacity` property, or the `rgba` or `hsla` notation for the background color of the element, depending on what effect you want to achieve. See: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/sN8uU/

Comment: Good job putting a `filter: alpha(opacity=50);` inside a `div:last-of-type` selector so M$ will never see the filter ;)